# Array list in Redux state

Tags: redux, immutable.js

This is a question about state in Redux js. I have an array list in the state:

```
{
  list: list
}
```

According to Redux document, I should not modify the state in the reducer. I want to append a new item to the list. Should I clone the list, or simply append the new item to the list:

```
let newList = state.list;
newList.push(newItem);
return {
  list: newList
}
```

The above code actually modify the original state, because the newList is the same list as "state.list". Is this an OK practice, or should I use immutableJS to clone the list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are mutating the list here and giving back the same reference. I believe something like below should make a new copy

```
return { list: [...state.list, newItem] }
```

It's not mandatory to use immutableJS. but you need to make sure not to mutate the state.

take a look at [deep-freeze](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze) library to make sure that your state is not being edited.

this [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-object-mutations-with-object-assign-and-spread) from Dan (creator of redux) should help as well

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't keen on the spread operator, you can also do:

```
var newList = list.slice(); // copy the array
newList.concat(['item']);
return {
  list : newList
}
```

Comment: In fact `Array#concat` behaves in an immutable fashion. It returns a new array whilst leaving the initial one as is. So not only is it unnecessary to create a copy of the array, the above code will fail because you haven't assigned the return value.